# Evaluation error in if function. Also plot error in code. In R

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm trying to write RPS game. Below is my code. Running it in Rstudio nothing happens but in basic R i get an evaluation error in line 29, "missing value where true/false needed" and also the plots get errors for unequal x,y axis. There must be something simple i'm missing as to why only that if is wrong. Thanks for your time.

```
Np<-1200    #pop size
Ng<-300 #generation time    

P<-matrix(data=NA, nrow=Np/2, ncol=2)   #matrix of pop
strategy=c('Ro','Pa','Sc')
P1<-sample(strategy, size=Np, replace=TRUE, prob=c(1/3,1/3,1/3))    #pop with equal probs of any strategy

# "res <- matrix(P1, nrow=Ng, ncol=3)  #matrix for results" # defunct remove!
fR=c()
fP=c()
fS=c()
# result vectors for each strategy

# res<-matrix(NA, ng,3) # matrix as per example. results vectors returned null.

pR<- 0.5
pP<- 0.5
pS<- 0.5
# probabilities of success in each encounter of pX winning.

for(i in 1:Ng) {
    for(j in 1:(Np/2)){
  if(P[j,1]=='Ra'& P[j,2]=="Sc"& runif(1)<pR){P[j,2]<-"Ra"
    }
    if(P[j,1]=='Pa'& P[j,2]=="Sc"& runif(1)<pS){P[j,1]<-"Sc"
    }
    if(P[j,1]=='Sc'& P[j,2]=="Ra"& runif(1)<pR){P[j,1]<-"Ra"
    }
    if(P[j,1]=='Ra'& P[j,2]=="Pa"& runif(1)<pP){P[j,1]<-"Pa"
    }
    if(P[j,1]=='Pa'& P[j,2]=="Ra"& runif(1)<pP){P[j,2]<-"Pa"
    }
    if(P[j,1]=='Sc'& P[j,2]=="Pa"& runif(1)<pS){P[j,2]<-"Sc"
    }
}   # each row fights and winner replaces with appropriate probability.

P[,2]<-sample(P[,2])  #randomise interactions 
fR=c(fR, sum(P=="Ra"))
fP=c(fP, sum(P=="Pa"))
fS=c(fS, sum(P=="Sc"))
}


plot(x=fR,y=Ng, ylab="frequency", xlab="Generation", col="black", type="l")
lines(fP, Ng, col="green")
lines(fS, Ng, col="red")
```

Comment: I think all you need to do is populate your matrix once before going through all the if statements.

Comment: Thanks for the help that's pretty much it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Error in if (P[j, 1] == "Sc" & P[j, 2] == "Ra" & runif(1) < pR) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
> i
[1] 1
> j
[1] 1
> str(P)
 logi [1:600, 1:2] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

It errors out when `i` an `j` are 1. (Unlike other functions, the for-loop indices remain in their last assignment if a loop terminates abnormally.)  You cannot test with "==" when your `P` matrix is all NA. The `if` function raises an error when the test returns `NA`. Maybe you meant to write the inner loop tests with `P1`? Perhaps yhis will be a happier setup meta-strategy:

```
P<-matrix(data=NA, nrow=Np/2, ncol=2)   
strategy=c('Ro','Pa','Sc')
P[]<-sample(strategy, size=Np, replace=TRUE, prob=c(1/3,1/3,1/3))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was telling to run the wrong matrix. Also sorted out the plotting errors. all is well.